# dif with occurs check

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, occurs-check

Is there a dif with occurs check?
This here works:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.7)

?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true). 
true.

?- dif(X,f(Y)), X = Y.
X = Y.
```

But the above is not feasible, since occurs check
is a global flag, I get the following:

```
SWI-Prolog console for thread 3

?- X=f(X).
false.
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/issues/135#issuecomment-488348886) is a sketch of an implementation that would.

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered a bug in SWI?

Comment: My point is that `(=)/2` is equivalent to `unify_with_occurs_check/2` when OC is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Now, [Scryer](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/) supports `dif/2` with occurs-check when the corresponding flag is set:

```
?- use_module(library(dif)).
   true.
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
   true.
?- dif(-X,X).
   true.
?- dif(-X,Y).
   dif:dif(- X,Y).
?- dif(-X,X), X = a.
   X = a.
```

Comment: Good. In addition to that, a dedicated `dif_with_occurs_check/2` would be nice, too - parallels `unify_with_occurs_check/2` nicely...

Comment: @repeat: And unify_without_occurs_check/2 as well? Would be the best for subsumes_term/2

Comment: OK, but there may be systems that cannot implement `unify_without_occurs_check/2` without looping. And `subsumes_term/2` might be implemented differently internally.

Comment: @repeat: Systems with a looping algorithm would have to implement it differently. But yes, it might only work for systems with rational trees. BTW, did you understand what exactly is happening in Tau, when the occurs check is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

In my system, I made a new predicate `dif_with_occurs_check/2`. As the name says, it is `dif/2` with occurs check, so no need to set a flag. But there is an additional benefit, `dif/2` is optimized to listen to fewer variables:

```
/* listens only to changes in X */
?- dif(X, f(Y)).
/* listens to changes in X and Y */
?- dif_with_occurs_check(X, f(Y)).
```

This is necessary, so that we can wake up `dif_with_occurs_check/2` when change the variable `Y` for example to `Y = X`. `dif_with_occurs_check/2` will then remove its own constraint `X = f(Y)` which has become `X = f(X)` and therefore obsolete.

```
?- dif(X,f(Y)), X = Y.
X = Y,
dif(Y, f(Y))
?- dif_with_occurs_check(X,f(Y)), X = Y.
X = Y
```

**Open Source: Module "herbrand"**
https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/jekmin/headless/jekmin/reference/term/herbrand.p